# Dynamically merging file modules with directory modules in Python

Tags: python, module, package

Given a directory with the following structure:

```
├── foo
│   ├── bar
│   │   └── baz.py
│   └── bar.py
└── foo.py
```

and the following file contents:

## foo.py

```
class Foo:
    pass
```

## foo/bar.py

```
class Bar:
    pass
```

## foo/bar/baz.py

```
class Baz:
    pass
```

I would love to be able to do all of these things from some other file:

```
from foo import Foo
from foo.bar import Bar
from foo.bar.baz import Baz
```

i.e. as if the definitions in each file were "merged" with the module definitions comprising the directory with the same name. How can I accomplish this in a dynamic way (whether involving `__init__.py` or otherwise) that won't require me to manually specify each path?

When I place empty `__init__.py` files in each directory and attempt to perform the above imports, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo import Foo
ImportError: cannot import name 'Foo'
```

which seems to me to suggest that the `foo.py` file has been overridden by the `foo` directory so that the definitions in `foo.py` are not visible.

Comment: do you mean you wish you could _avoid_ typing out the `foo.bar.baz`? in which case yes this is fairly easy with an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: No, I'm fine with typing the imports exactly as shown. I've updated the question with the error I get when I attempt to do so.

Comment: When I say "in a dynamic way that won't require me to manually specify each path", what I mean is that I wouldn't like to have to update the `__init__.py` files, for example, to include each new file/directory for which I want this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing:

```
import foo
print(foo.__file__)
```

with the folder structure you show I'd expect the result to be something like:

```
.../foo.py
```

But when you add an `__init__.py` to the `foo` folder it would instead be:

```
.../foo/__init__.py
```

with python packages you cannot actually import a folder so what ends up happening is that you import the `__init__.py` file from that folder instead of the `foo.py` so all you need to do is move the `foo.py` into the folder and *rename it* to `__init__.py` and you can then `import foo` or `from foo import Foo` the same way as you have it set up now.

Comment: Thanks -- this makes plenty of sense, and sounds much better than trying to manually merge two separate sets of definitions.

Comment: I really wish [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) described what the `__init__.py` was actually for instead of just "__init__.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the \__all__ variable"  **the \__init__.py file contains package level variables**